# Google Sheet: Automatically Populate Table with Multiple Different Cell Values Associated with Most Recent Date In Another Table Using Formulas

Tags: date, google-sheets, indexing, formula, vlookup

I have the following sample table in the exact layout below inside Google Sheets.  Please note the actual table has a lot more rows and dates so this is just a simple example.

|  |  | Tom | Jim |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11/27/2023 | value 1 | 42 | 70 |
|  | target | 33 | 65 |
| 12/4/2023 | value 1 | 37 | 66 |
|  | target | 29 | 54 |

I have another table that I want to automatically populate every time I update my first table with additional rows of data.  Specifically, I want to populate the new table with value1 and target from the most recent date of the first table.  So in the above example I want my output table to look like this:

| Metrics | Tom | Jim |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value 1 | 37 | 66 |
| target | 29 | 54 |

The most recent date is 12/4/2023 and I want its corresponding values for Tom and Jim.

I have tried playing around with filter() and max() formulas but they don't end up populating the cells correctly.

What Google Sheet formula should I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You may try: (also this assumes that **dates** in Column_A are always goin' to be in **ascending** order)*

```js
=xlookup($F2,$B:$B,C:C,,,-1)
```

[image]